# Tree traversal - inorder position

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, position, traversal

I am trying to find the value of the `kth` node in tree, using recursive in order traversal.

The code below is done with recursion, but my implementation is way too slow.

Can someone please give me a hint how to make it faster? (`reihe` and `pos` are class variables, they both start from 0, and I save the final result in `pos`).

Here is what I have done so far, and any help would be really appreciated:

```
void valueAtPosition(int k) {

            if(this.left!=null){
                left.valueAtPosition(k);
            }
            if(reihe++==k){
                pos=this.elem;

            }

           else if(this.right!=null){
                right.valueAtPosition(k);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code? Can you give some more info about the tree (is it balanced? does it have some ordering? how big is it?) and about the request (will you have one or several? if you will have several, you could speed up requests after the first one).

Comment: Meanwhile, if the value was down the left side, you still check the middle (and possibly the right). I think you're missing an "else" there...

Comment: Yes sure, I'll post the whole code but it is kind of long though. And yes this is a binary search tree. Some of my friends did it by saving for each node how many nodes it has beneath, but I am not sure how to do that, it is supposed to look something like this: http://prntscr.com/752ajs and I my code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/2DsZAJr8 @fstanis

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov I am not sure if I understoot 100% of what you said, but this is supposed to go inorder, for example the value at the fifth position, so I am not sure how to make it stop, when it reaches the fifth position, instead of going the whole tree through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the need for `reihe` (and I'm assuming it's not english since it makes no sense as a variable name to me). I've passed the variable k as a return value. When it reaches 0, I return the current value and stop searching.

```
int valueAtPosition(int k) {

    if(this.left!=null k >= 0){
        k = left.valueAtPosition(k);
    }

    if(k == 0){
        pos=this.elem;
    }
    k--;

    if(this.right!=null && k > 0){
        k = right.valueAtPosition();
    }

    return k;
}
```

Comment: Ahah yes it's german :D Thanks it looks cleaner than my code, but it is not working...

Comment: what happens? what returns?

Comment: Also, k is 0 indexed, i.e the first element in the traversal will be found by calling valueAtPosition(0)

Comment: it is supposed to run a test, and the test stops and gives this result: http://prntscr.com/752f1f. It works with the way that I wrote it, but it takes too long, so it is unacceptable for the system

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!!!!!!! It is working, because I did something wrong the first time. You just divided the time in half of what the function needed!!!! Thank you soooo much! I am so grateful